# Login Page in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cloud9-ide

I'm using cloud9 server and i connect my DB to this server.

I have some PHP code for simple log in, and it isn't working.

The connection to DB is on, but is always show me the msg

> "username and pas is not correct" (getting result==0)

This is my code:

```
    <?php


      ob_start();
      session_start();



if(isset($_POST['button'])){
$username = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
}

//MySQL Database Connect
 $conn = mysql_connect(getenv("IP"),  getenv("C9_USER"), "");

if (!$conn) {
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('homework5', $conn);

 if (!$db_selected) {
 die ("Can't use internet_database : " . mysql_error());
  }


 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT *
FROM users
 WHERE (userName = '$userName') and (password = '$password') ;";

 $result = mysql_query($query);



     if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
    { ?>
 <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
  alert("The Password or The UserName is not Correct");
  </Script>
   <?php
  header("Location: login1.php?eror=1"); die();
  }


     $userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
// store the needed session data for the home page session
   session_regenerate_id();
   $_SESSION['userName'] = $userData['userName'];
   $_SESSION['Level']= $userData['Level'];
   //End the current session and store session data.
   // header() is used to send a raw HTTP header to open execute home.php

   session_write_close();

    switch($userData['Level']){

     case 1  :    header("Location: maneger.php"); die();   break ;
     case 2 :    header("Location: intredection.php"); die();   break ; 

     default: header("Location: login1.php?eror=2"); die();  break;
    }
```

Comment: Change `$userName` to `$username` since you're using `$username = $_POST['userName'];` variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development. It would have spotted that typo.

Comment: Plus, don't store plain text passwords. You're bound to get a severe shot of SQL injection and a hack in the back.

Answer (score 2):

This is your select query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (userName = '$userName') and (password = '$password') ;";
```

Above select query should be like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (userName = '$username') and (password = '$password')";
```

You set the username to $username.But in the select query you use $userName and extra ; also.

Answer (score 0):

Check for $username. you are using camelCase. change $userName to $username in query